# Deleting many PartitionKey-unique entities from Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

The problem that we have is that we need to delete more than 600 unique entities (mostly with *unique Partition Keys* and empty Row Keys) from Azure Table Storage, and we are looking for an effective way of doing that.

The batch delete will require that *All entities in a given batch must have the same partition key*, which is not our case.

Is deleting them one by one the only way of doing it? Or is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is deleting them one by one the only way of doing it? Or is there
>   another way?

Yes, unfortunately that's the only way to delete entities with different partition keys.